# Unable to download Huggingface API Transformers

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, huggingface-transformers, safe-tensors

After downloading tensorflow and PyTorch, and running `pip install -q transformers`, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for safetensors
ERROR: Could not build wheels for safetensors, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Here is a screenshot of the whole thing:
[image]

Not sure how to fix this. I tried upgrading pip and running this command as an answer to a similar post said to: `pip3 install setuptools_rust docker-compose`, but the same error keeps showing up.

Don't understand the issue and dont know how to fix it.

Comment: which is your current pip and torch version?

Comment: @Jeril pip: 23.2.1, torch: 2.0.1

Comment: are you using windows os?

Comment: @Jeril no im using macos

Answer (score 2):

I installed Rust (https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) and resourced my `~/.bashrc` and then it worked for me.

Comment: how do you resource `~/.bashrc `? i dont know what that means

Comment: I mean `source ~/.bashrc` which runs the file again in the current shell. Alternatively you can just open a new terminal.